# Apache flume twitter agent not streaming data

Tags: java, hadoop, twitter, cloudera, flume

I am trying to stream twitter feeds to hdfs and then use hive.  But the first part, streaming data and loading to hdfs is not working and giving Null Pointer Exception.

This is what I have tried.

**1.** Downloaded **apache-flume-1.4.0-bin.tar**. Extracted it. Copied all the contents to **/usr/lib/flume/**.
in /usr/lib/ i changed owner to the user for flume directory.
 When I do **ls** command in **/usr/lib/flume/**, it shows

```
bin  CHANGELOG  conf  DEVNOTES  docs  lib  LICENSE  logs  NOTICE  README  RELEASE-NOTES  tools
```

**2.** Moved to **conf/** directory. I copied file `flume-env.sh.template` as **flume-env.sh** And I edited the JAVA_HOME to my java path `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle`.

**3.** Next I created a file called **flume.conf** in same `conf` directory and added following contents

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = <Twitter Application API key>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = <Twitter Application API secret>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = <Twitter Application Access token>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = <Twitter Application Access token secret>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = hadoop, big data, analytics, bigdata, couldera, data science, data scientist, business intelligence, mapreduce, datawarehouse, data ware housing, mahout, hbase, nosql, newsql, businessintelligence, cloudcomputing

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:8020/user/flume/tweets/%Y/%m/%d/%H/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 600

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

I created an app in twitter. Generated token and added all the keys to above file. **API Key I added as consumer key**.

I downloaded the flume-sources jar from [cloudera -files](http://files.cloudera.com/samples/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) as they mentioned [in here](https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example).

**4.** I added the **flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar** to **/user/lib/flume/lib**.

**5.** Started Hadoop and done the following

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/flume/tweets
hadoop fs -chown -R flume:flume /user/flume
hadoop fs -chmod -R 770 /user/flume
```

**6.** I run the following in **/user/lib/flume**

```
/usr/lib/flume/conf$ bin/flume-ng agent -n TwitterAgent -c conf -f conf/flume-conf
```

It is showing JARs it is showing and then exiting.

When I checked the hdfs, there is no files in that. `hadoop fs -ls /user/flume/tweets` and it is showing nothing.

In hadoop, **the core-site.xml**  file has following configuration

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
        <fina1>true</fina1>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run the following command and it got worked

```
bin/flume-ng agent –conf ./conf/ -f conf/flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent
```

Comment: You are not geeting the error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.conf.Configuration.getRequestHeaders()Ljava/util/Map;
  while running? Because this method does not exists in the API jar.

Comment: I am not getting any error. It is running perfectly. I use apache flume 1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I used this command and it is working

```
flume-ng agent --conf /etc/flume-ng/conf/ -f /etc/flume-ng/conf/flume.conf - Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent
```